# If he loves God, he will sacrifice his son. - is this correct usage in a review article?

Tags: present-tense, conditionals

How do we use conditionals in a review of a story?

**Example 1**

> God asks Abraham to sacrifice his son to test him. **If Abraham loves God, he will sacrifice his son.** And he is going to, so he loves God.

Is Example 1 a correct usage?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a review of a story; it is a retelling of a story.

You've chosen to tell the story as a present-tense narrative (which is okay, this is the historical present) and so the situation of "sacrifice his son" is in the future (from the perspective of the narrative). So a normal first conditional is correct "If he loves God, he will sacrifice..."

It might be different if you'd chosen to tell the story as a past narrative.